# How to swap two canvas elements in HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

On my canvas I have two rectangles drawn. The first with a larger height and second with a smaller height.
Here is a screen shot: [image]

In my code I represent them with classes and then instantiate them :
Here is how I do it:

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(x, y, width, height, color, value) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.color = color;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // draw function of this rectance will let it appear on the screen;

    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height , this.color, this.value);
    }

    // the update function will swap the rectangle's property and redraw them again

    
    update(obj1, obj2) {
        var temp; 
        // saving the values of the first rectancgle in the temp variables

        for(var key in obj1) {
            this.temp = this.obj1[key];
            this.obj1[key] = this.obj2[key];
            this.obj2[key] = this.temp;
        }

        this.obj1.draw();
        this.obj2.draw();        
    }


}
var rect2 = new Rectangle(100, y-20, 50, 25, "pink", 40 );
rect2.draw();

var rect1 = new Rectangle(160, y, 50, 5, "black", 20);
rect1.draw();


rect1.update(rect1, rect2);
```

What I want to do is now make the pink rectangle appear in place of black and black in place of pink. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(x, y, width, height, color, value) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.color = color;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // draw function of this rectance will let it appear on the screen;

    draw() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height , this.color, this.value);
    }

    reposition(x,y) {    
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}
var rect2 = new Rectangle(100, y-20, 50, 25, "pink", 40 );
rect2.draw();

var rect1 = new Rectangle(160, y, 50, 5, "black", 20);
rect1.draw();

// do this – after some wait, click or however you like to trigger it
let buffer_x = rect1.x, buffer_y = rect1.y;
rect1.reposition(rect2.x,rect2.y);
rect2.reposition(buffer_x,buffer_y);
rect1.draw();
rect2.draw();
```

Comment: I think that the reposition method will need a this.draw() function.. Also the height , widht color and value properties need to be change. But thank you , your reposition method helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can try swap location of obj1 and obj2!!
ex:

```
var x1 = this.obj1.x, y1 = this.obj1.y;
this.obj1.x = this.obj2.x;
this.obj1.y = this.obj2.y;
this.obj2.x = x1;
this.obj2.y = y1;
```

after this, call update